# How do I mate two 2x6s together to make a 4x6 beam?

Tags: wood

I need to make (3) 4×6×12 beams and (2) 4x6x10 beams for an acquaintance  who is building a lean-to horse shelter. What type of fastener should I use and how many? Must I use adhesive and if so what type?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that lumber nominal dimensions are not actual dimensions.  A 2x6 is really 1.5" x 5.5" not 2" x 6" as the name suggests.  So a built-up beam made from two 2x6's is actually just 3 inches wide.  If you're supposed to use a 4x6 timber, you might not be able to substitute a built-up beam made from two 2x6's.

Using built-up beams made from doubled up or tripled up dimensional lumber is an everyday framing method.  The most common way to build them is simply nailing them together.  There are different standards for the specifics of nailing them up.

This illustration from [Details for Conventional Wood Frame Construction](https://www.awc.org/codes-standards/publications/wcd1) shows nails 32" apart in a W pattern, with three nails at the ends.  The document specifies 20d nails.  Other standards may specify different types of nails and spacing.

[image: Nailing Built-up Beams]

It may not seem like a lot of nails, and there's no glue, but it's not necessarily better to make the beam more rigid;  this type of beam may function better if the pieces are allowed to move a little so that all the pieces contact the material they support.  The important thing is to stick to whatever the design intended, and that that design is something applicable codes allow.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a laminated beam. Since this is for a horse barn, I'm going to assume you're dealing with pressure treated wood.

You'll need a couple of things

1. Construction adhesive. Make sure it's something designed for outdoors (i.e. [Liquid Nails heavy duty](https://www.liquidnails.com/products/heavy-duty-construction-adhesive-1))
2. Lag bolts. Use the screw-in types with a washer head (something like [this](http://www.spax.us/en/power-lags/t-star-washer-head.html), making sure it's rated for pressure treated wood). Since we're talking 2x4s, 3" lag bolts should be fine. Note that if you want to use deck screws, you can give that a shot, but the lags will perform better, given that this is structural. You're probably not going to spend a lot more on the lags vs deck screws given the size of the project.

Place one board flat on the ground and put a generous bead of adhesive on it. Be sure to get as much coverage as you can  (i.e. don't have large bare spots). Now place the other board on top and put a few lags on this side. I would put 3 or 4 on this side. Now, flip it over and put 3 or 4 on this side. If you elected for deck screws, I'd put one every 12-16" or so, zig-zagging them on one side so you're alternating them with the other side.

Comment: To have it match dimensional lumber it's common to sandwich ply in between the pieces.

Answer (score 0):

You must laminate them together (somehow).

Imagine a stack of sheets of paper, each sheet 5.5" x 10 feet, the full stack is 3.5" high.  Is that as strong as a 4x6? No, because each sheet of paper will simply bend individually (independently).  So will a pack of six 1x6’s or a stack of two 2x6‘s. That's what makes the 4x6 stronger than six 1x6‘s.

Howver you may notice that a 500 sheet pack of copy paper *in its package* has some resistance to bowing out that the unwrapped stack does not.  That is because the package holds it bound in a stack. The sheets are not free to slide past one another, so they can't bow as easily.

That's what lamination is all about.  It keeps the individual 1x6's or 2x6's from spreading or sliding past each other, making them more rigid.  Even the aforementioned stack of paper could do alright if it were glued together effectively.

The most effective way is to use glue, obviously.  I am cautious of gluing to new wood, especially treated wood, because it is so wet internally, and in my experience that makes glue ineffective.  I like my lumber dried a year per inch (so 9 months on two-by's, which are 1.5" thick).   By the way, four-by's are 3.5" thick so you have 1/2" of thickness to make up if that dimension is critical.

However you can also lam with bolts or screws.

Now if you want to make it extraordinarily strong, steel is freakishly strong when kept on edge.  Consider a laminate of

- two-by
- 1/16" steel sheet
- 3/16" plywood
- 1/16" steel sheet
- two-by

All tightly bolted together in a stack (gluing wood to steel won't provide very good adhesion). This plays to the strength of both materials, the stiff but not particularly strong wood forces the strong but wet-noodle steel into its strongest shape.  And also keeps weight down since the stiffener is wood, not steel.

Comment: _"... dried a year per inch (so 9 months on two-by's, which are 1.5" thick) ..."_.  This doesn't add up?  Perhaps you meant a _half year_ per inch?

Comment: @MarkL Stack it so you can dry it on both sides.